# AWS Route53 doesn't resolve my domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I tried to administrate my domain by AWS route53, so I changed name server in domain administrater.('Domain administrater' means corporate which I got my domain name. I have no idea how to say about that, sorry.)

I got IPv4 by Elastic IP and I regestered my domain to A record in route53, with my Elastic IP.

That was OK. I could browse my page with my domain name.

And I tried to ready my mail account with my domain name, so I registered 'mail.MYDOMAIN' in MX record and A record with my Elastic IP.

Then DNS couldn't resolve my domain name.

I had no idea to resolve that, so I removed my all my record set, I made new record set.
And I changed name server in domain administrater too.
But DNS still doesn't work.

result of nslookup is here.

```
    $ nslookup MYDOMAIN
    Server:         10.0.1.1
    Address:        10.0.1.1#53

    ** server can't find kyttmmm.net: NXDOMAIN
```

```
    $ nslookup MYDOMAIN ns-1441.awsdns-52.org
    Server:         ns-1441.awsdns-52.org
    Address:        205.251.197.161#53

    Name:  MYDOMAIN
    Address: 52.68.XXX.XXX #exactly my EIP
```

Does anyone know cause about this?

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to visit us at Route 53 forum (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=87) where we can properly assist you? Stack Overflow isn't the best place to discuss or troubleshoot any customer specific issues so I hope we can help you out in the forum.

Comment: See https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en#clientHold ... as of right now, the domain name shown in the question in in "ClientHold" status with the registrar, so it isn't going to resolve.  You'll need to resolve this with the registrar -- it's not a technical problem.